# Does using a widget tool like GetSiteControl or HelloBar create a security risk?

Tags: web-application, javascript, appsec

There are 3rd party tools to insert widgets into a website. By inserting a snippet of Javascript tools like [HelloBar](https://www.hellobar.com/) and [GetSiteControl](https://getsitecontrol.com/) allow users to easily create popups, toolbars, and chat windows.

What type of exposure does this create for a website owner? Specifically, is it possible that these tools can be used to collect information inputted into fields on the site?

Comment: there's no "perms" in JavaScript; any script you run can do anything it wants, including spying on form values. Whether or not they behave badly depends on the source, but they all have the _potential_ to be bad.